# How to browse area list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, area

I am trying to learn Javascript,

Can someone tell me if it is possible to browse an area List with Javascript ?

If yes how can I do it?

Here is my HTML Code:

```
 <map name="rx" id="rx">
    <area href="Link.gg" coords="137,92,25" shape="circle" alt="Blabla">
    <area href="Link1.gg" coords="227,93,25" shape="circle" alt="Blabla1">
    <area href="Link2.gg" coords="295,105,25" shape="circle" alt="Blabla2">
 </map>
```

What is the JS Code to browse this ?

If it is possible I have got one more question,

HTML Code:

```
<area href="Exemple.gg" coords="295,105,25" shape="circle" alt="Unicorn">
```

How can I get the value of the href and the alt ?

```
( `var myvar = "Exemple.gg"; var myalt = "Unicorn";`)
```

I just want to get the text from the href and alt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const areas = document.querySelectorAll('area'); // use more precise selector if needed
let myElement;

areas.forEach(el => {
    if (!myElement && el.getAttribute('alt') === 'Red') {
       myElement = el;
    }
});

console.log(myElement)
```

Comment: Hi @givhug thank you so much. 
i have a last question,  HTML Code  : `<area href="Exemple.gg" coords="295,105,25" shape="circle" alt="Unicorn Red M">` can i select only area which contain "Red" in the alt ?

Answer (score 0):

To get area list under your map element use

```
var areaList = $("map#rx").find("area");
```

To get area attributes just use

```
var href=$("area").attr("href");
var alt=$("area").attr("alt");
```